# Do I need to enable CORS when my API is on a subdomain of my main website?

Tags: rest, http, cross-domain, cors

I have a RESTful api sitting at a subdomain of my website, so it is setup like below:

```
api.blah.com - RESTful api
blah.com - Website
```

When I try to do HTTP requests though, I get the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '(index)' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I thought that because it was on the same domain, this should work, do I need to enable CORS or is there something else I need to do?

The API is built on ASP.Net Web API, and website is AngularJS based.

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes you have to enable it. You have to send [CORS allow headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) from server side to your browser. This is because a subdomain is a different [origin](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454). You probably have to allow HTTP methods like PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS as well. At least I guess angular sends that kind of requests too. You have to handle preflight requests (OPTIONS) by these new methods.

Comment: @JMK Can you please share what did you change so that it worked for you? Thanks

Answer (score 26):

The origin is a combination of scheme/host/port. So, if your origin is http://store.company.com/ and you are trying to access http://news.company.com/dir/page.html, it would be considered cross origin.
More examples here -

[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: This is the better answer since it actually explains the WHY.